# unable to unmarshal json to an object

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

i have a attribute (that produced by a REST service and catched by invokeHTTP processor) in JSON format like this:

```
test => {"key":"value"}
```

and then i want to put it in flows JSON content using JOLT processor, my content is something like this:

```
{
    "id": 123,
    "user": "foo"
}
```

and my JOLT specification is this:

```
[{
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
        "interest": "${test}"
    }
}]
```

the problem is here that, in JOLT advanced window with test attribute nifi cannot put json object and shown this error:

> "Error occurred during transformation"

and when run processor this detailed error is become alerted:

> "unable to unmarshal json to an object"

---

my desired result is this:

```
{
    "id": 123,
    "user": "foo",
    "interest": {"key":"value"}
}
```

*another possible question is... am i choose right solution to overcome this situation?
i have a flow that contain JSON content and with invokeHTTP that sent to a REST service and then response store in attribute and then with JOLT processor i combine those together (previous JSON and new JSON in attribute)*

Comment: it's worked with escaping JSON:
{\"key\":\"value\"}

but when insert in JSON that have stringed because of double quotation (" ") 

{
    "id": 123,
    "user": "foo",
    "interest": "{\"key\":\"value\"}"
}

any idea?

Answer (score 2):

As you are having **test** attribute associated with the **flowfile**

- Try with **`ReplaceText`** processor instead of `JoltTransformJson`

***ReplaceText Configs:***

Search Value

```
}
```

Replacement Value

```
,"interest": ${test}}
```

Character Set
UTF-8
Maximum Buffer Size

```
1 MB
```

Replacement Strategy

```
Literal Replace
```

Evaluation Mode

```
Entire text
```

[image]
***Input:***

```
{"id": 123,"user": "foo"}
```

***Output:***

```
{"id": 123,"user": "foo","interest": {"key":"value"}}
```

Comment: thanks, this is my second approach. but what about JOLT problem? is that a bug?

Comment: @meh, it looks like a bug. even if we use escapeJson the output is `"{\"key\":\"value\"}"` but your expected output is `{"key":"value"}` without `"` quotes (processor is not allowing to define as `"interest": ${test}`).

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same issue in Nifi 1.6.0, the Advanced editor converted the input without issue, but automatic processing failed.  The error I received:

`due to com.bazaarvoice.jolt.exception.JsonUnmarshalException: Unable to unmarshal JSON to an Object.: Unable to unmarshal JSON to an Object`

It turns out the problem were some unescaped Unicode characters in the input that were not visible and had been lost on copy/paste when debugging.  To fix it and also find the error I added ":escapeJson()" for each of the attributes. For example:

`{"key":${myvalue:escapeJson()}}`

Looking at the output flow file I was then able to determine the attribute was causing the problem.

The same solution I found was also posted here:
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/JoltTransformation-unable-to-marshal-json/m-p/230679/highlight/true#M192526